# Remove by index value from props array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to remove a value by Index of the props array passed from another component.

```
[...this.props.data].splice([...this.props.data].indexOf(oldData), 1)
const {tableData, ...application} = oldData;
this.props.deleteData(application);
```

It deletes the data, but not just the selected value, but both values at the same time. I guess the problem is in the splice..indexOf

```
oldData :is the selected row that needs to be deleted.
```

Comment: You shouldn't modify `props` and remove the data from the parent `state` instead

Comment: but If I want to modify it? how can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concat from `0` to `index - 1` and from `index + 1` to `length - 1`.  So a simple `this.props.data.slice(0, index).concat(this.props.data.slice(index) + 1)` Should work.

Imo `concat` is easier to read and reason about because it does not mutate your array.

A filter could  also work for you:

```
 const filterIndex = target => (_, i) => i !== target;

 newData = data.filter(filterIndex(index));
```

To use the filter version is pretty easy, two ways, depending on the use case.

1) Remove a specific index without leaving holes in the array

```
const target = this.props.data.indexOf(oldData);
const newData = this.props.data.filter((_, index) => index !== target);
```

2) Remove a specific value from the array (all its occurrences) without leaving holes in the array

```
const newData = this.props.data.filter((data) => data !== oldData);
```

Those two are slightly different as the first one will only remove the first occurrence of `oldData` and the second all
occurrences.

Comment: To understand the code should be like this. `this.props.data.slice(0, this.props.data.indexOf(oldData) - 1).concat(this.props.data.slice(this.props.data.indexOf(oldData))` I tried and is not working.

Comment: my bad, off by one error. I would recommend using the filter version much more explicit than the `slice` `concat` stuff.

Comment: adz5A would you be able to show me how can I use your implementation with mine? by using props.

Comment: I updated my answer, let me know if it is clearer for you. Have a nice day.

Comment: Thanks fixed the problem, I added the value as a state and checked the nextProps, then set them up, if not matching, then implement your code. THanks